# How to read an .ini file submitted by spark-submit in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I submit my application and my .ini file to Spark like this:

```
spark-submit \
--master ... \
--files /path/of/config.ini \
--py-files /path/of/py.zip \
/path/of/my_script.py
```

And in `my_script.py`, I try to read `config.ini` like this:

```
with open('config.ini') as f:
  print(f.readline)
```

But it returns an error told me `No such file or directory: config.ini`, what's the right way to read the content of `config.ini`?

Comment: Are you giving the full path for `config.ini` in the Python script?

Comment: @user2314737 If I use the full path, should I upload the .ini file to machine which spark cluster is running first?

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your code

**** Sample.py******************

```
import sys
# read argumets

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
      .master("local[1]") \
      .appName("sample app") \
      .getOrCreate() 
      

file=sys.argv[1]
print("file name :",file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(file) as f:
         print("read file :",f.readline())
```

****** config.ini ***********
this is Sample text

********  Spark-submit *********

spark-submit --master local \path to\sample.py \path to\config.ini

this is running perfectly without error.

i think you are missing path :-

provide full path to read file content

File=sys.argv[1]
with open(\path to\file) as f: